# Django redirect user after login

Tags: django

I have a problem when trying to redirect a user after login to the `base.html` which is in main template folder. Django can't find this template.

I get the error:

```
 Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

 1. admin/
 2.
 The current path, base.html, didn't match any of these.
```

How do I properly set up django to make the redirection work?

Django structure:

```
accounts
main_folder
    settings.py
    urls.py
staticfiles
templates
    base.html
```

Short app structure

```
accounts
    templates
        accounts
            login.html
    urls.py
    views.py
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

accounts urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import*

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_view),

]
```

accounts view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get posted data
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        # handle user authentication
        if user is not None and user.is_active and user.is_authenticated:
                login(request, user)
                # move user to main page
                return redirect('base.html')

    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason to run your own authentication I would highly recommend you make use of djangos built in authentication modules. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58029365/601245 `the better more django way`

Answer (score 3):

Your redirection is not to a template but to a url. So in your current code on successful login you would be redirected to http://localhost/base.html.

You will need to change the redirect to a path:

```
return redirect('/some-url/')
```

Or better still make use of named urls.

```
return redirect('some-named-url')
# this would turn a named url into a url string such as '/auth-url/'
```

You urls file would look something like:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import*

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_view),
    path('auth-url/', <some_view>, name='some-named-url'),
]
```

**The better more django way.**

If you are not doing anything too extreme you really should look at making use of djangos built-in authentication. Not only is it tried and tested but it also will get patched if a vulnerability was ever discovered.

To do this you would change the urls to be something like:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView,
    LogoutView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'login/',
        LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'),
        name='login',
    ),
    path(
        'logged-in/',
        <Your LoginView>,
        name='logged_in',
    ),
    path(
        'logout/',
        LogoutView.as_view(),
        name='logout',
    ),
]
```

And in your settings file:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login' # this is the name of the url

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login' # this is the name of the url

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'logged_in' # this is the name of the url
```

Comment: thank for fast replay, I was able to find the answer my self

Comment: No problem, i am glad you found the solution yourself. Please read the bottom part of my answer as it might be a better option for your application.

Comment: In case anyone gets maddened like I did by this, if you've created a namespace make sure to include it in the URL. ie. 'namespace:loginReirectUrlName'

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

modify view.py

```
return redirect(home)
```

add in view.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

and in urls.py

```
path('home/', home, name='home')
```